# Extract specific cluster of k-mean image quantization

Tags: python, opencv, k-means

I need to analyse only the next region around the light source as image below.
I am using a mix os kmeans and cv2 to create clusters:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  

    
image = cv2.imread('1.png')
k =6
# Quantization
i = np.float32(image).reshape(-1,3)
condition = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER,20,1.0)
ret,label,center = cv2.kmeans(i, k , None, condition,10,cv2.KMEANS_RANDOM_CENTERS)
center = np.uint8(center)
final_img = center[label.flatten()]
final_img = final_img.reshape(image.shape)  
plt.imshow(final_img)
plt.show()
```

[image]

But when I try to get this region -I am guessing cluster 1 is the target- appear an error:

```
masked_image = np.copy(final_img)
cluster = 1
masked_image[label == cluster] = [0, 0, 0]
masked_image = masked_image.reshape(final_img.shape)
# show the image
plt.imshow(masked_image)
plt.show()
```

The error:

> masked_image[label == cluster] = [0, 0, 0] IndexError: boolean index
> did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is 389 but
> corresponding boolean dimension is 188276

Comment: It appears you need to reshape/flatten either `masked_image` or `label`.

Comment: "I am guessing cluster 1 is the target"  -- order will be random. but maybe you can sort the cluster centers by luminosity / lightness